# What was the siddur that was used by the Rebbe R' Elimelech of Lizhensk?

Tags: prayer-book, chassidic-rebbe, nusach-ari

I was wondering which siddur the Rebbe R' Elimelech of Lizhensk might have used. I was thinking that perhaps he used the Berditchever but then again he was a disciple of the Mezritcher Maggid together with the Ba'al haTanya and might have used his siddur.

Comment: A more likely possibility would be the Siddur of Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov. That was the Siddur of the Ba'al Shem Tov and the Maggid and was the foundation for the Alter Rebbe's Siddur.

Comment: That would make sense. Do you know where I could purchase a complete volume of this siddur?

Comment: related https://treasuresofashkenaz.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/the-noam-elimelech-on-changing-from-nusach-ashkenaz-to-sfard-not-a-simple-matter/

Comment: http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=5993&strReferer=search&PPGR=0

Comment: http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=5994&strReferer=search&PPGR=0